# Print different length of spaces in C#

Tags: c#, whitespace

How can I print different length of spaces in C#?

```
Write(number*" ");
```

doesn't work here.

EDIT: But it works in Python.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What is the `Write` method? What is `number`? What is the expected output?

Comment: Why dont you use a for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, there's no `*` operator taking a string and an integer.

The simplest option is probably to use the `string(char, int)` constructor:

```
Write(new string(' ', number));
```

Depending on your actual use case, you might want to look at [string.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`string.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too, if you're *actually* trying to pad an existing string.

Comment: That's fast.! :) chuck!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that:

```
  Write(new String(' ', number)); // <- ' ' character, number times
```

That's, probably the simplest way. You may also want to look `String.Format` esp. if you try to print out a padded data. For instance:

```
  // Prints out myData padded left up to 10 characters
  Write(String.Format("{0,10}", myData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this snippet:

```
int index = 0;
while(index<number)
{
   System.Console.Write(" ");
   index++;
}
```

You can encapsulate this in a *wrapper* function, and call it as

```
printblank(number);
```

using:

```
void printblank(int number)
{
      int index = 0;
      while(index<number)
      {
           System.Console.Write(" ");
           index++;
      }
}
```

Thereby you can use this function repeatedly, as per your requirement.

Comment: This is C# not, Java.

Comment: change System.out.Write(" "); to Console.Write(" ");

Comment: Why bother with tags then? If I post a question asking how to do recursion and tag it as `C#`, and get an answer in `SQL` is that answer still valid?

Comment: Jeez, that was an honest mistake, I work with both , so its become a habit. :) Rectified it now.

Comment: Beware the post police are here! +1

Comment: Yea, I will be doubly careful from now :)

Comment: why don't use `for`, it's much more brief and easier to understand

Comment: I don't think it would make that big a difference with for. Function is small already.